# Need Box2D benchmarks

Tags: c#, java, benchmarking, box2d, jbox2d

I've ported jbox2d to c# and I want to check if my results are identical.

Does anybody know if there are some benchmarks which I can use as ideal results or running tests.

When I say benchmark I mean some strict description of box2d world (for example in form of code) and exact positions, velocities and etc. of every body in the world.

Thank you.